# Why do my images not form in a single row within latex?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to load four images in a single row, all aligned with same sizes, to save space. However, they are all scattered in 2 different rows. Here is my code -

```
\begin{figure}
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment1.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:env}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment2.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:galaxy}
\endminipage\hfill

\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment3.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment4.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage
\caption{Stuff}
\label{Environment_2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: For one, the blank line in the middle of your code provokes a new paragraph.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `\minipage...\endminipage` instead of `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank line in the middle of the OP's code produces a new paragraph, preventing the four figures from ending up on the same line.  Also, I added an `\hfill` that I thought was desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment1.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:env}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment2.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:galaxy}
\endminipage\hfill
% <-- GET RID OF PARAGRAPH BREAK
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment3.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage\hfill% <--PROBABLY WANT AN \hfill
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Environment4.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\endminipage
\caption{Stuff}
\label{Environment_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]